# Saga GIS at command line in OSGeo4W - 'shapes to grid' tool - sqlite input

Tags: saga, sqlite, rasterization, command-line

I have been using the Saga 'Rasterize' plugin in QGIS to rasterize spatial data from sqlite format (road networks, and intersections) to tiff. I find this tool more flexible than the gdal_rasterize equivalent. Whilst i can batch convert files in qgis, i would like to implement this tool (actually saga 'shapes to grid' tool - which i believe is one and the same as the qgis saga rasterize tool) at command line in windows batch scripts. However, I am struggling to find the correct syntax to do this - in terms of selecting the sqlite file and then the table within it. How do i enter the file and table into the saga tool at command line? There only seems to be the facility to enter an input file and a table attribute at command line, no input table name? The tool must surely support sqlite, as the equivalent in qgis works fine?